# PHP script for text field that only allows links

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to php and was wondering if there's a script that would only allow users to post URLs in a text field rather than text. Thank you!

Comment: There's probably one out there - but this isn't the place to ask. If you've tried programming it, or have even found the right examples in the manual, ask a programming question and you'll get help.

Comment: My apologies. I thought stackoverflow was for that. Never mind, google it is ;)

Comment: It's intended for programming help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP filter_var function with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL to validate the user entry.

For more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp